# Daily job using Evernote's job library

Tags: android, jobs

I just wanna to fire local push notification at the specific time every day!
I found in the documentation I can achieve this. Below code:

```
public class MyDailyNotMorning extends DailyJob {

public static final String TAG = "MyDailyJob";

public static void schedule() {
    // schedule between 1 and 6 *PM*
    DailyJob.schedule(builder, TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(6));
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected DailyJobResult onRunDailyJob(Params params) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
            .setContentTitle("Morning")
            .setContentText("It's time to send a photo!")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            //   .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setLocalOnly(true)
            .build();


    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext())
            .notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);
    Log.d("myTag", "onRunJob: notification setted daily success:morning");

    return DailyJobResult.SUCCESS;
}
}
```

Say in this case notification receives at 1 a.m(or p.m), so the issue is what the second parameter of this method. Or how can I achieve "receive local notification" at 8 a.m (only 8 a.m. not p.m)? Please help me?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes from the docs :**

> // schedule between 1 and 6 AM

```
DailyJob.schedule(new JobRequest.Builder(TAG), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1),TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(6));
```

It's not P.M . If you try **18:00:00** it's P.M. It follows 24-Hour clock.

---

**Code**

It's my theoretical thinking (testing needed) **,** but you can try this below then comment if worked.

You set the `DailyJob` between **08:00:00** and **08:00:05**. That means a five-seconds-difference between start-time and end-time.

You can use `TimeUnit.Seconds.toMillis(5)` **,** just like what you've used before.

```
public class Tasker extends DailyJob {
    static final String TAG = "do_update_value_job_tag";

    static void schedulePeriodic(Context context) {
        Long startMs = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8);
        Long endMs = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8) + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5); //←←←
        JobRequest.Builder requestByTag = new JobRequest.Builder(Tasker.TAG).setUpdateCurrent(true);
        DailyJob.schedule(requestByTag, startMs, endMs);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected DailyJobResult onRunDailyJob(@NonNull Params params) {
        //do stuff
        return DailyJobResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel() {
        //do stuff
        super.onCancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay understand.But if job is ended and then what will happen and what is the behaviour ?

Comment: If Job ends , it will run the next day at desired time... I've written a small app that adds +10 to the money deposited in currency everyday at 6am and installed it on my mom's phone. The last time I touched the app is more than 2 months. From then, it works smooth and I've never seen it to fail.

Comment: It it working? If it is then please accept the answer.

Comment: is this still working if the device is restart or change date time?

Comment: The concept of this snippet is clean and precise. It's just I'm afraid that it would clear itself after reboot or change the date-time as AlarmManager does and we need to check and reset it again